# Flutter : firestore where in list

Tags: android, list, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have a list of Strings, and i want to select all in collection "post" where name is in the list. How can i do it.

```
List<String>followings = [];    
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('feelings').
        where('userId', isEqualTo:followings).snapshots(),
```

Comment: you will need to use multiple streams and merge into one stream

Comment: an example please